# Can we use index like array index to access List<T>?

Tags: java

I am wondering if we can use index to access List

For example:

```
List<Integer> list; 

list[5]     //blah....
```

Comment: No. You are asking for a C# feature which isn't present in java.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Since `[]` is an operator and java does not support operator overloading you can't use it with List. Instead you have to use the `set(int index, T value)` and `get(int index)` methods, which may be verbose but provide exact the same functionality.

Answer (score 35):

[`List.get(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) allows you to access elements using the index.

Answer (score 8):

There are plenty of good answers here, but I just want to point out that `list.get(i)` is the same as `list[i]` only if list is implemented with an array (i.e ArrayList). If it is a LinkedList you are not really indexing with `get`, but rather iterating.

So if you use `get()` with the interface type List, especially in a loop, you should check how it's implemented, as `get()` with ArrayList is O(1) whereas `get()` with LinkedList is O(n) (much slower).

Answer (score 6):

You can access List elements using their index through the use of the [get](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method:

> get
>
> public Object get(int index)
>
> Returns
>   the element at the specified position
>   in this list.
>
> Parameters: index -
>   index of element to return.
>
> Returns:
>   the element at the specified position
>   in this list.
>
> Throws:
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the
>   index is out of range (index < 0 ||
>   index >= size()).

Keep in mind that the index in Lists is 0 based.

Answer (score 4):

No, you're restricted to `List.get (i)`.

The brackets `[]` are defined on syntax level, not as method-name, so you can't override them. They are used just for arrays exclusively.

If you like to migrate to Scala, a more modern language for the JVM, you'll find an unified access to arrays and lists, but both with `()` parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

an alternative to using `get(int)` is to create an Array using `toArray()`

```
List<T> list = ...

Object[] array = list.toArray();
```

if T is *known*, `toArray(T[])` can be used to return `T[]` instead of `Object[]`.
The use of `toArray` is only meaningful, instead of `get`, if an array is really needed (lots of accesses).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this in Java.

Comment: @Downvoter Patrick was correct in saying that `list[5]` is not possible in Java, although he didn't mention any alternatives.

Comment: @asgs - I'm not the "Downvoter", but the answer is not useful, it's actually wrong. Yes, "we can use index to access List" using `list.get(int)` or, if really *needed*, `list.toArray()[5]`   [:-)

Comment: But don't do that, it would be very inefficient to allocate an array with `toArray` just to access an element.

Comment: I agree, but it can be done in Java... and not that inefficient if doing lots of accesses.

Comment: It is however possible to do in C#